# Trying to Find the Best way to pull DB item in Joomla 2.5 Component

Tags: php, mysql, loops, joomla, components

I have a database which has 2 columns `id` and `title.`  What is the best way for me to filter through these table values to display the matching `title` results when a user submits the `id` value in a form for a Joomla 2.5 component (admin view)?

When I look at the documentation here:

`http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase`

I see that by using Joomla’s API I can use a shorthand to create this connection.  I have tried:

```
$userSubmittedIDValue = $_GET["userSubmittedIDValue"];

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('title')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent_table'))
->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote('$userSubmittedIDValue'))

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Unfortunately, this gives the following error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Then the error points to `$results = $db->loadObjectList();`

I just need to pull that value and apply it to a php variable so that I can use it as required.  Any ideas?

---

Okay thanks to the first answer I have realized that I was missing a semi-colon.  The trouble I am having now is still in pulling the value from the array using `foreach`.  I have tried adding the following:

```
foreach (array($results) as $userSubmittedIDValue) {

echo $results;

}
```

But this just prints the word `Array`.  I am getting close, but something is still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error due to the fact you have a missing semi colon after your query.

So, change this:

```
->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote('$userSubmittedIDValue'))
```

to this:

```
->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote('$userSubmittedIDValue'));
```

Simply note the `;` on the end

Once done, you can use a `foreach` loops to display your results.

So your final code to use would be this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*')
->from('#__mycomponent_table')
->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. $db->quote($userSubmittedIDValue));

$db->setQuery($query);    
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

I completely forgot to mention before that you also have to remove the single quote wrapped around `$userSubmittedIDValue` in the query as shown in my code above.
Hope this helps

Comment: That was definitely the reason the error was showing up, Thanks!  I have added some info to the question about using `foreach` do you think you could comment on what I am doing wrong so that we can close this question out?

Comment: Yes!! That did it.  Thanks so much for that final update, it was what cleared everything out for me.